# Implicit conversion of a function to a second-order-function only works if the function to convert has at least two parameters

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, higher-order-functions

I have a problem of implicit conversions and higher-order functions. It seems that an implicit conversions of a function to a second-order-function only works, if the function to convert has at least two parameters.

Works:

```
implicit def conv(foo: Integer => String): String => String = null
```

Does not work:

```
implicit def conv(foo: Integer => String): String => String => String = null
```

Works:

```
implicit def conv(foo: (Integer, Integer) => String): String => String => String = null
```

Full example with point of failure:

```
{
    implicit def conv(foo: Integer => String): String => String = null

    def baadf00d(foo: Integer): String = null

    def deadbeef(foo: String => String) = null

    deadbeef(conv(baadf00d))

    deadbeef(baadf00d)
}

{
    implicit def conv(foo: Integer => String): String => String => String = null

    def baadf00d(foo: Integer): String = null

    def deadbeef(foo: String => String => String) = null

    deadbeef(conv(baadf00d))

    deadbeef(baadf00d) // <-------- DOES NOT COMPILE!
}

{
    implicit def conv(foo: (Integer, Integer) => String): String => String => String = null

    def baadf00d(foo: Integer, bar: Integer): String = null

    def deadbeef(foo: String => String => String) = null

    deadbeef(conv(baadf00d))

    deadbeef(baadf00d)
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like an implicit resolution wart in Scala to me. Which Scala version is this?

Answer (score 3):

```
  implicit def conv(foo: Integer => String): String => String => String = ???

  def baadf00d(i: Integer): String = ???
  def goodf00d: Integer => String = _ => ???

  def deadbeef(foo: String => String => String) = ???

  deadbeef(conv(baadf00d))

  deadbeef(baadf00d) // <-------- DOES NOT COMPILE!
  deadbeef(goodf00d) // <-------- COMPILE!
  // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

The issue is how implicit conversions work on Scala and the fact that there are curried and uncurried functions in Scala.

This is something that SHOULD work but doesn't and is probably just yet another compiler bug (get ready to meet many more as you use Scala more and more).

EDIT: As for your last example

```
implicit def conv(foo: (Integer, Integer) => String): String => String => String = null

def baadf00d(foo: Integer, bar: Integer): String = null

def deadbeef(foo: String => String => String) = null
```

That's because there the function definitions do match. The conv expects a function `(Int, Int) => String` and a normal method definition (uncurried) in scala, like how `baadf00d` is defined, turns into that.

For example, a function:

```
def f(a: Int, b: Int): String
```

Gets turned into a

```
(Int, Int) => String
```

Notice that the 2 Ints are tupled! This is NOT the same as:

```
Int => Int => String
```

If you were to redefine baadf00d into:

```
def baadf00d: Integer => Integer => String = _ => _ => ???
```

That code won't compile, because baadf00d is now "different", even though it is doing the same thing.

For more information, look at the definition of the objects:

```
Function1, Function2, Function3 ....
```

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Function2

Comment: Okay, so the reason why the second conversion doesn't work is just because of a compiler bug I guess...

Comment: Yep. In Scala, `baadf00d` and `goodf00d` should get turned into `(Int) => String` and `Int => String` respectably. Now these things SHOULD be the same, but for some reason, Implicit resolution thinks that they are different. The fact that you can pass `baadf00d` into `conv` proves that they are the same, is just implicit resolution being too stupid to figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

```
implicit def conv1(a: Function1[Int, String]): Function2[String, String, String] = null
def baadf00d1(i: Int): String = null
def deadbeef1(arg: Function2[String, String, String]) = null  
deadbeef(baadf00d) // compiles
```

It's the conversion between `A => B` and `Function1[A,B]` that isn't happening.

Also there is a `Function` type in `Predef` -- notice the type differences here:

```
scala> val f1: Function[Int, Int] = null
f1: Function[Int,Int] = null

scala> val f2: Function1[Int, Int] = null
f2: Int => Int = null

scala> :type f1
Function[Int,Int]

scala> :type f2
Int => Int
```

It's an alias to `Function1`, but with different type bounds (as pointed out in the comments below).

Comment: Or you can even assign `baadf00d` to a val using `val baadf00d2 = baadf00d _` and then it works

Comment: :type and :kind treat them uniformly in the REPL, making it appear even more strange.

Comment: from Predef.scala 
"type Function[-A, +B] = Function1[A, B]"

Comment: Do you think the type bounds difference make it not match the implcit in his example above?

Comment: `Function1[A, B]` and `A => B` are the same thing (in a type context).

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if it was converting it to Function instead of Function1 causing his implicit to not match.